# Listen to missingTranslation event

Tags: event-handling, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I would like to collect strings, that has not been translated because translation is missing.

1. I would like to enable this event for all translations. Now I can do this by setting it right before translating, but this should be a global setting.
2. I would like to have a function called if this event is triggered.

Am I able to do this?

Thanks for any help!

(This is Zend Framework 2.2 and Zend\I18n.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF2 actually has this event built-in in the Translator.
By default the translator component is not triggering any events, you have to explicitly enable it.

In you module.config.php

```
return array(
    'translator'
        'event_manager_enabled' => true
    )
);
```

Now you can attach a listener to the event.

```
$translator = $serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator');
$translator->getEventManager()->attach('missingTranslation', function($event) {
    //Do some stuff when translation is missing
    var_dump($event->getParams());
});
```